# How to execute a .py from a php file in a web interface?

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to do a web interface with HTML and PHP. This interface would have a button that when you click a `.csv` file is created and the name of the file would be the date of today. In that CSV I will save in real time the data that I read from a serial port of a Raspberry Pi 4.

My problem is that when I click on the button of the interface then the file `crear_csv.php` doesn't execute the file `.py`, so no file `.csv` is created.
Can you help me?

Code **crear_csv.php**

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['crear_csv'])) {
    $fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d"); // Obtiene la fecha actual en el formato YYYY-MM-DD

    // Ejecutar el código de Python para crear el archivo CSV
    $output = shell_exec("python mediciones.py $fecha_actual");

    // Mostrar el resultado de la ejecución del código de Python
    echo $output;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
        <title> Pagina Principal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="crear_csv.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="crear_csv" value="Crear archivo CSV">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code **mediciones.py**

```py
import serial
import csv

import sys

i=0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)  

csv_file = "{fecha_actual}.csv"

with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='\n') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    
    while i<500:
        try:
            raw = ser.readline().decode().strip()  
            values = raw.split(',')
            writer.writerow([values[0], values[1]])
            i=i+1

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error al leer los datos: {e}')
         
ser.close()
```

I test the `file.py` and it works properly I think my problem is in the file `crear_csv.php` that function exec is not working well.

Comment: `var_dump($output)` gives what? Is error logging enabled in both platforms, and being viewed? Have you outputted something in python to verify it starts opening the file?

Comment: Not familiar with python but how is `fecha_actual` associated with the shell argument there? Shouldn't be `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: You might need to enable python cgi on server (apache2) to exec python scripts.

Comment: @ArpitJain that would only be if the OP was trying to execute the python script directly from a HTTP request to Apache, not with PHP as an intermediary. In the PHP context, python is effectively being executed in a similar as if it was from the command-line.

Comment: Most likely has to do with the current working directory. Your file has probably been created, just not in the place you expect it to be.

Comment: Make sure your python file is within the same directory of you PHP script. Make sure your python script has executable permissions. Make sure your web server has execute permission and create file permissions for the directory. Also you could add error report to your script on $output i.e `if ($output === null) {report error} else { echo $output }`

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.conf user:webroot config ,it must has permission.

You can use `su - webroot` change user and execute your index.php demo file to check it.